# Video recording with Twilio

Tags: ios, twilio

Is it possible to record only one person in video call with Twilio?

I don't see any examples in their documentation about video recording for one person.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you absolutely can, just make the 2 people join the same room. 
You can give it a try with Twilio's sample app here: [Twilio Video Sample App](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/quickstart-sample-apps)

Just make sure the 2 devices running this app connects to the same room.

Comment: I need video recording for one person and audio recording for another person in one file for a certain part of the conversation

Comment: @juve100 I don't get it, but anyway it doesn't matter. If you are talking about a particular function I might be able to help you out, but if it's a lot of functions put together like writing a small project, I'm afraid you won't find help on SO